# Better way of getting a GIT commit message by short hash?

Tags: git, bash, awk, grep, git-log

I am currently getting my commit message for a certain commit hash by using this below:

```
hash='b55da97'
git log --pretty=oneline ${hash} | grep "${hash}" | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

These seems extremely inefficient though. Is there a smarter or cheaper way to do this, or am I stuck with grepping and awking?

Comment: You're already quite close, just limit output to 1 commit and use a different --pretty: `git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%s $hash`

Comment: @torek plus one to your comment, and +1 and accepted if you want to post this as an answer.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`git log` takes (among other things):

- `-n num` to limit the number of commits shown: choose 1 (and if *`num`* is 9 or less you can just write `-num`, hence, `-1`, for short)
- `--pretty=format:string with directives` to change the log output format.  The `%s` directive gets the commit "subject", which is what you also get with `oneline`.

Hence: `git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%s $hash` (or `git log -1 --pretty=format:%s`) will do the trick here.

For a complete list of format directives, see the [git log documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html#_pretty_formats), under "PRETTY FORMATS" (about halfway down).

Answer (score 12):

Depending on how much of the commit message you actually want, there are several pretty-format specifiers that you can use:

```
      ·  %s: subject
      ·  %f: sanitized subject line, suitable for a filename
      ·  %b: body
      ·  %B: raw body (unwrapped subject and body)
```

So something like `git log -1 --pretty=format:%b <hash>`, or use one of the other specifiers (I think `%s` is probably closer to what you are doing now). The `-1` limits `git log` to just the one commit, rather than walking the history tree.

Answer (score 8):

I like having the important stuff dumped into a single line... Here's what I use, built off other answers on this page:

#### git_log_for_commit.sh

```
IT=$(git log -1 --pretty=format:"%an, %s, %b, %ai"  $*)
echo "$IT"
```

#### output

```
jdoe, WORK1766032 - Added templating engine, WIP, 2013-08-15 14:25:59 +0000
```

Answer (score 3):

An even shorter answer than is listed here is

`git log --pretty=oneline {your_hash} | grep {your_hash}`

Comment: There is also `git log --oneline` but the hash is short instead of the full version.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
git show --pretty=format:"%s" -s "${hash}"
```

Answer (score 1):

This may short it some

```
git log --pretty=oneline ${hash} | awk '$0~var {print $2}' var="${hash}"
```